# JQuery DataTables carga json, pero no rellena la tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

JQuery DataTables carga json, pero no rellena la tabla.

Este es el código:

```
    <table id="tabla" class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                            <th>Num</th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Comentario</th>
                            <th>Visualizacinoes</th>
                            <th>País</th>
                            <th>Categoría</th>
                            <th>Fuente</th>
                            <th>Fuente</th>
                            <th>Fuente</th>
                            <th>Fuente</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                            <th>Num</th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Comentario</th>
                            <th>Visualizacinoes</th>
                            <th>País</th>
                            <th>Categoría</th>
                            <th>Fuente</th>
                            <th>Fuente</th>
                            <th>Fuente</th>
                            <th>Fuente</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tabla').dataTable({
                ajax: "todos.php"
                columns: [
                        {data:"number"},
                        {data:"id"},
                        {data:"name"},
                        {data:"coment"},
                        {data:"views"},
                        {data:"country"},
                        {data:"category"},
                        {data:"font"}
                ]
        });
});

</script>
```

Este es el JSON:
http://mtvuy.000webhostapp.com/todos.php

Este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y acá está el sitio subido:

http://mtvuy.000webhostapp.com/prueba.php

En la consola se muestra el siguiente error:

*jquery.dataTables.js:4743 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at jquery.dataTables.js:4743
    at callback (jquery.dataTables.js:3864)
    at Object.success (jquery.dataTables.js:3894)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:5)*

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Por lo pronto entre `ajax` y `columns` te falta una coma.

Comment: Y eso es todo, este [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsfnykq0/4/) demuestra que, a menos que la respuesta de tu `todos.php` sea incorrecta, tu ejemplo funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aunque es verdad que, como ha comentado Juliosor

> entre ajax y columns te falta una coma.

Considero que el problema principal es la llamada a la API. He invocado a la API de otra forma, especificando cuál es tu array de datos, porque por defecto, la llamada que has hecho no espera un array de datos, espera un objeto con un atributo "data" con el array. Te adjunto el ejemplo modificado con el que he podido conseguir cargar tu tabla:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tabla" class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Num</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Comentario</th>
                <th>Visualizacinoes</th>
                <th>País</th>
                <th>Categoría</th>
                <th>Fuente</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Num</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Comentario</th>
                <th>Visualizacinoes</th>
                <th>País</th>
                <th>Categoría</th>
                <th>Fuente</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tabla').dataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url : "http://mtvuy.000webhostapp.com/todos.php",
                    dataSrc : function ( json ) {
                        return json;
                    },
                },
                columns: [
                    {data:"id"},
                    {data:"number"},
                    {data:"name"},
                    {data:"coment"},
                    {data:"views"},
                    {data:"country"},
                    {data:"category"},
                    {data:"font"}
                ],
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad. Un saludo